# Как сделать код более простым (если это возможно)

Tags: javascript

Хочется как-то сделать код проще, но чтобы он не терял своей функциональности.
Одна из причин, потому что не совсем понимаю его.
Можете помочь сделать этот код на уровне новичка или объяснить его?

Это калькулятор, который принимает римские и арабские числа и возвращает результат.

```
const digits = {Z:2000, M:1000,CM:900,D:500,CD:400,C:100,XC:90,L:50,XL:40,X:10,IX:9,V:5,IV:4,I:1};

function roman2arabic(str){
  if (!/^[IVXLCDMZ]+$/i.test(str)) throw new Error('Incorrect roman number format: ' + str)
  return str.toUpperCase().split('').reduce(function(r,v,i,arr){
    const [ a, b, c ] = [ digits[arr[i]], digits[arr[i+1]], digits[arr[i+2]]];
    if (b && c && a <= b && b < c)
      throw new Error('Incorrect roman number format: ' + str);
    return b > a ? r - a : r + a;
  }, 0)
}

function arabic2roman(num){
  if (!/^\-?\d+$/.test(num+'')) throw new Error('Can`t convert that arabic numeric to roman: ' + num)
  if (num < 1) return '';
  let result = '';
  for (let key in digits)
    while ( num >= digits[key] ) {
      result += key;
      num -= digits[key];
    }
  return result;
}

function calculator(string){
  let badChars = [];
  string = string.replace(/[^IVXLCDMZ\d+\-*\/]/gi, chr => {
    if (chr !== ' ') badChars.push(chr);
    return '';
  });
  if (badChars.length > 0) 
    throw Error('Символы не допустимы: ' + badChars.join(' '));
  let isRoman = /^[IVXLCDMZ]+$/i,
    vars = string.split(/[+\-*\/]/g),
    action = string.match(/[+\-*\/]/)[0];
  if (vars.length !== 2) 
    throw Error("Должно быть лишь два операнда");
  let r = vars.reduce((s,v)=> s + isRoman.test(v),0);
  if (r === 1)
    throw Error("Оба числа должны быть либо римскими, либо арабскими, исправьте выражение: " + string);
  else if (r === 2)
    vars = vars.map(v=>roman2arabic(v));
  else if (vars.reduce((s,v) => s + /^\d+$/.test(v)) < 2)
    throw Error("Приведенные операнды не допустимы, проверьте выражение: " + string);
  if (vars.some(v => v < 1 || v > 10))
      throw Error("Допустимо значение операндов лишь от 1 до 10 включительно")
  let result = Math.floor(eval(vars.join(action)))
  return r === 0 ? result.toString() : arabic2roman(result)
}
```

Comment: Добавил вашему вопросу метку "инспекция-кода". Пожалуйста прочтите ее полное описание и приведите вопрос к нужному виду.

Comment: простота относительна ... конкретней бы

Comment: Можно пройти какой-нибудь начальный курс по javascript.
Потом гуглить непонятные слова, читать документацию.
Пробовать разобраться на простых программках в 1-2 строки, а уже потом комбинировать. Задавать конкретны вопросы.